# adding two fields in single relationship in pyrocms

Tags: pyrocms

Is it possible to show two fields combine is single relationship field type.

I have two streams:

```
Stream 1 : Webinars
Stream 2 : Coaches (Fields first name, last name )
```

I want to add "coach first name" and "coach last name" in 'one relationship field' to Webinar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I can think of, is creating a new field in the coaches stream (named "display_name" for example) and use this as a title column for your coaches stream.

Combining the first name and the last name into this new field could either be done with javascript in the corresponding forms, or by triggering an event after the coaches form has been submitted.